# Parse dynamic key value pair object in JQ

Tags: jq

I would like to parse the following object

```js
{
  "test_account": {
    "us_east_1": {
      "i-a023adfa2": "Key=a,Value=c key=2,Value=3",
      "i-23adfw34r": "Key=t,Value=n"
    }
  }
}
```

I pass account and region as arguments to the script and am able to get the object but not able to parse the returned object. I want to extract key which is ec2-instance id and value which is combination of tags that needs to be added. I am using shell script to parse this json using Jquery.

Here is partial script..

```shell
instances = ${jq -r ".$1 | select .${2//[-]/_} != null) | .${2//[-]/_}". <path of json file> | tr '\n' ' ')
```

I call this with  "sh <scriptname> test-account us-west-2" ...

I couldn't parse the returned object to get key and value into respective variables. Can someone please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:jquery]? Looks more like `jq` to me

Comment: I was using them interchangeably..  Yes, i want a JQ solution that works in shell

Comment: You know that jQuery is a JavaScript utility right? Absolutely nothing to do with the shell

Comment: So you want to turn "Key", "Value", and "key" into shell variables? What happens if a variable is redeclared ("Value" in your example)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to parse a string like `"Key=a,Value=b Key=c,Value=d"` into a JSON object. The assumptions are that key-value pairs are separated by a single space, the key is separated from the value by a comma and that there are no spaces or commas in either the key or value. You are allowed to have as many key-value pairs as you want. The key and the value don't have to appear in that order, e.g. a key-value pair may be encoded as `Value=a,Key=b`

Given these assumptions, the following snippet parses a string in the above format into a JSON object:

```bash
KEY_VALUE_PAIRS="Key=a,Value=b Key=c,Value=d"
echo "\"$KEY_VALUE_PAIRS\"" |
    jq '[
        split(" ") | .[] | split(",") |
            { (.[]|select(startswith("Key="))[4:]) :
                .[]|select(startswith("Value="))[6:]}
    ] | add | . // {}'
```

Result:

```json
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

Details for the different parts:

- `split(" ") | .[] | split(",")` - split the whole string into an array of arrays. Each inner array has two string elements, one for the key, one for the value.
- `{ (.[]|select(startswith("Key="))[4:]) : .[]|select(startswith("Value="))[6:]}` - convert each inner array into an object with a single element, where the key is taken from the array element that starts with `Key=` and the value is taken from the array element that starts with `Value=`. The `Key=` and `Value=` prefixes are stripped.
- `[ ... ] | add` - merge all objects into a single object containing all key-value pairs
- `. // {}` - if the string doesn't contain any pairs, return an empty object instead of `null`

Integrating the above snippet into the original script is left as an exercise to the reader.